# Is it reliable to use string comparison for comparing semantic version strings

Tags: php

It seems like comparing semantic version strings, like this, always outputs the correct result - if the version on the left is greater than the expression would be `true`:

```
'1.12.2' > '1.11.12'
```

Are there scenarios when it wouldn't?

Comment: No it isn't reliable, which is why PHP provides a [version_compare()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php) function that can do it reliably

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are there scenarios when it wouldn't?

Yes, lots:

```
echo '1.12.2' > '1.101.12'; # true
```

You cannot compare version strings this way. You may have found some that work, but it's purely coincidence.